# How to prevent scrolling effect when clicking 'back'

Tags: html

Check www.cnn.com. If you scroll down, click one of the links near the bottom and click 'back' in your browser you will see the top of the page loading first. After a while the browser 'jumps' back to where it was when you clicked the link. In different browsers it might take shorter or longer, but it's really annoying. Is there any known (or unknown) method to prevent this from happening, other than opening the links in a new window?

Comment: I'd say that changing this adversely affects usability and the behavior expected by the user, and probably shouldn't be done in the first place. Further, this cannot be done with Javascript, but your question only states HTML.

Comment: I noticed that iframes cause a problem as well. The page won't scroll until they are loaded, even when the sizes are set

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent this because it is maintained by the client (web browser). However, on pages with a smaller amount of content, the 'jump' will not be as obvious as pages that take longer to bring back into memory.

You could, of course, open the pages in a new window (as you mentioned) or use `iframe`s, but both of those are bad work arounds. Simply reduce the amount of content as much as you can (particularly images and scripts). Keep in mind that since all large websites have this "problem", the user will be used to it and, for that reason, are more likely to blame the speed of their computer or browser than your site.

You don't want to design your websites to *need* use of the back button anyway.

Comment: It would be possible to script the page so that it displays nothing until finished loading (so after the jump occurs) but I agree that would be a bad idea. It is greatly preferable to optimize page loading so that the jump is over with quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably about as close as you could get, but there's going to be a noticeable little flash. Also, I only tried this in Chrome. Might work differently in other browsers.

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    }, 1);
};
```

Either way, I tend to agree with other posters -- this functionality exists in browsers for a reason, and users expect it.